# Unable to import the global.css file to the root layout in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Folks, I am new to Next.js 13.

I have created a project using Next.js 13 and playing around with the new `app` directory.

I am trying to apply styling using Tailwind CSS. I have followed the Next.js documentation below:

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/tailwind-css

The documentation says to import the `global.css` stylesheet to the root layout (`app/layout.js`) in order to apply the styles to every route in your application. I tried to follow this step, but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here are my code snippets:

app/layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import "../styles/global.css";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="w-full h-20 bg-white border-b border-gray-300">
        <ul className="w-40 h-20 p-4 flex justify-between items-center list-none">
          <li>
            <Link href="/blog">Blog</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/projects">Projects</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/books">Books</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

styles/global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `import "../styles/globals.css";` instead.

Comment: He's using the app router... your comment pertains to the pages router

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `global.css` but have named your file `globals.css`.

I did the same thing and took me a while to figure out haha!

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles/global.css";
```

this should work. you had 1 to many dot

Comment: The styles directory is not inside the app directory. It is inside the project root. Hence double dots (../)

Answer (score -1):

In nextJs you should import global CSS files only inside _app.js component as described in nextJs docs.

> Due to the global nature of stylesheets, and to
> avoid conflicts, you may only import them inside pages/_app.js.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

Comment: He's using the app router.  Your comment only pertains to pages router